# JavaScript associativea array - passing a string as array key: value pairs

Tags: javascript, string, key, associative-array

I know that I can create an associative array like this:

```
var MyAssocArray = {'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green'};
```

And I am very fond of using this method.

What I would like to do and am having trouble with is this:

I have strings saved like this:

```
var MyString = "'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green'";
```

And I want to be able to do this now:

```
var MyAssocArray = {MyString};
```

When I try that - I get this error:

```
invalid object initializer
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I achieve this?

---

I found a different solution using PHP and JavaScript. The associative array string is echoed in the JavaScript code:

```
var Multidimensional_Arr[Multidimensional_Array_Key_Name] = {<?php echo $String_Pulled_From_Database; ?>}; // i.e. 'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green'

// The same can be done for a one-dimensional array
var My_Single_Dime_Arr = {<?php echo $String_Pulled_From_Database; ?>}; // i.e. 'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [JSON](http://www.json.org) -- it's serialized JavaScript Object Notation and is pretty close to what you're doing.

You'd need to do

```
var MyAssocArray = JSON.parse(MyString);
```

Also, JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes; if you use simple objects, you can probably write code to just replace `'` with `"`" in your strings, but it's tricky if the strings contain double-quotes.

If you are using a browser that doesn't implement JSON.parse(), you can either use the implementation on the JSON website (see [links at bottom of this page](http://www.json.org/js.html)) or if you're using jQuery, there's [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

---

**Warning**: Your solution has a security risk, unless you are sure the data in the database has been sanitized:

```
 var My_Single_Dime_Arr = {<?php echo $String_Pulled_From_Database; ?>}
```

This is equivalent to a call to `eval()`; if your database string has any malicious code it can do bad things. This is one reason why JSON was invented -- it's easy to ensure that its contents are valid (and hence safe) before evaluated.

Your overall architecture, as you have presented it to us, is [data in database] -> server-side PHP -> client-side JavaScript. This is a classic example of serialized data. I realize you may have constraints to keep your system running without interruption, but a strict serialization format would make your system more secure.

Comment: Except, can the JSON object really be recommended without a browser support caveat yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the data is safe, then you could do:

```
var MyAssocArray = eval('{' + MyString + '}');
```

Comment: Also - I found another method:Since the string is being pulled out of a database - I found that I can populate the javascript associative array using PHP

Comment: Yeah.. this is not working for me. I tried it and get the error "--
invalid label"

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that.

To achieve what you want, use the split() function to split your string into comma-separated tokens first. Then each token should further be split by the ':' character.

Then push the two tokens obtained by the last split as the key and the value of your associative array.

Comment: that unfortunately won't work if any of the string keys or values has a comma in it.